# WebBrowser Control & Navigate help

Tags: c#

I can load a link into the webBrowser1.Navigate manual by adding a button. But, I can't get it to work while processing from the list box in a loop. Is there a response or wait function that's suppose to be added? Right now all I hear is clicking sounds and nothing happening in the browser control window.

```
private void start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listId.Items.Count != 0 && listCell.Items.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < listId.Items.Count; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < listCell.Items.Count; b++)
            {
                MakeReq(txtWebUpdate.Text + listId.Items[a].ToString() + 
                        "&admire=1", listCell.Items[b].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

void MakeReq(string Url, string Cell)
{

    try
    {
        txtSetUpdate.Text = (Cell);
        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(Url));
    }
    catch (System.UriFormatException)
    {
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Evan i'm trying to process each link, but as Ash said below it's canceling out each other in the loop process. So I guess I need to add something to make sure the process is complete first?

Comment: Getting WebBrowser events to fire requires pumping the message loop.  I will not mention Application.DoEvents as the workaround, that would be a bad idea.  More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/c-application-doevents/5183623#5183623  The proper way is a state machine that's pumped by the DocumentCompleted event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the code i ended up using.

```
   void WaitBrowserLoading()
    {
        while (webBrowser1.IsBusy)
            Application.DoEvents();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            if (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            else
                break;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your aim?

Here you just call `Navigate` which just initiates a navigation. It doesn't care what happens after it starts the process. So in your code the loop initiates several `Navigate`s in a row, each of which cancel the previous on if it has completed yet. Therefore the only one you will actual see complete will be the last one in your list.

Comment: how do I make it process each one, i just found .IsBusy would that help?